# Incorrect FQDN on Exim4 send-only SMTP mail server

Tags: email-server, exim, smtp, fqdn

I am pretty new to Linux systems and I am trying to send e-mail to my gmail ID using exim4. I found many tutorials for exim4 online and I am doing exactly that, however I never receive any email.

The log file shows:
/var/log/exim4/mainlog

```
2015-01-28 20:27:23 1YGdtD-0003Tx-7N <= root@xyz-pc.mymachine.pbx U=root P=local S=406
2015-01-28 20:27:23 1YGdtD-0003Tx-7N ** *XXXXXXX@gmail.com R=nonlocal: Mailing to remote domains not supported
2015-01-28 20:27:23 1YGdtD-0003U1-Ei <= <> R=1YGdtD-0003Tx-7N U=Debian-exim P=local S=1279
2015-01-28 20:27:23 1YGdtD-0003U1-Ei ** root@mymachine.pbx <root@xyz-pc.mymachine.pbx> R=nonlocal: Mailing to remote domains not supported
2015-01-28 20:27:23 1YGdtD-0003U1-Ei Frozen (delivery error message)
2015-01-28 20:27:23 1YGdtD-0003Tx-7N Completed
```

This is my /etc/hosts file:

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.1.1   xyz-pc.mymachine.pbx xyz-pc

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

On running command hostname:

```
xyz-pc
```

Also, I checked that my port 25 is open and listening

netstat -a -n -p | grep :25

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    114/exim4     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      12114/exim4
```

I don't understand where am I going wrong? Also, I am not sure about what is FQDN? mymachine.pbx is what I entered manually by my choice! should it be different? is it necessary to have existing FQDN? ( I know, I sound dumb here, but I have no idea how to find my FQDN ?

I am on Comcast home internet.. Is there any chance my FQDN should be something.comcast.net?

Please help. Thanks!

EDIT: I found on the internet that my FQDN should be hsd1.ma.comcast.net .. I changed it in the hostname file, still it's not working. Regarding the documentation, I went through that already but I am not sure about my domain name !! I am not hosting any website, just testing to send e-mails.

Answer (score 1):

start with the document `/usr/share/doc/exim4/README.Debian.gz` section 2.1

you want one of these settings: (as root do  `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`)

```
 2.1.1.1.1. internet site; mail is sent and received directly using SMTP
 2.1.1.1.2. mail sent by smarthost; received via SMTP or fetchmail
 2.1.1.1.3. mail sent by smarthost; no local mail
```

if you chose `smarthost`  see section 2.3.1